# Есть ли у слова "популярный" негативная коннотация?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, лексическая-сочетаемость

В Большом толковом словаре **популярный** - *пользующийся широкой известностью.* П. артист. П. поэт. П. журнал. П-ая песня.

Можно ли использовать это слово по отношению к чему-то негативному? Например, популярные заблуждения, популярные преступники и пр. Или оно предполагает исключительно положительный контекст?

Comment: Какое-то скудное там определение. В словаре Ушакова это значение представлено так: "Пользующийся большой известностью, общественными симпатиями".

Comment: В научной среде популярное изложение материала (как правило и априори) вызывает кривую ухмылку. Знания, почерпнутые из таких источников, профессионалами оцениваются словами *нахвататься верхушек*.

Comment: @shampar Это уже другое значение.

Comment: oleedd Разверните мысль.

Comment: Просто загляните в словарь. "Популярное изложение" — это не о том.

Comment: Да. Популярная лекция это другое. Другое по отношению к чему? К популярному убийце?

Comment: У вас "изложение", а "лекция" ещё может подойти к обоим значениям.

Comment: @oleedd Другое значение? А какое должно быть значение? Вопрос был простой "Есть ли у слова популярный негативная коннотация?"

Comment: Значений два (в словарях): ваше и "понятный" (*популярное изложение материала*).